# use skype4py to selectively mute/volume control group chat

Tags: python, windows, skype4py

I recently came across [skype4py](https://github.com/Skype4Py/Skype4Py) - couldn't find very extensive documentation/other questions, so asking here: is there a way to selectively mute/control volume of certain users in a group chat? The closest thing I've found is [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/electronic_cigarette/comments/4pw6kq/python_script_to_mute_your_skype_mice_when_you/) but it's not what I'm looking for.

I'm using windows, and if this isn't workable in skype4py for some reason or another, alternative solutions (besides not using skype) are appreciated :)

Thanks!